# What are the differences between "to snap the handcuffs" and "to click the handcuffs"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

In the dictionary

> [**snap**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/snap): 2 MOVE INTO POSITION [intransitive, transitive always +
> adverb/preposition] to move into a particular position suddenly,
> making a short sharp noise, or to make something move like this
>
> snap together/back etc
>
> The pieces just snap together like this.
>
> The policeman snapped the handcuffs around her wrist.
>
> snap (something) open/shut
>
> She snapped her briefcase shut.

---

> [**click**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/click_1?q=click) [intransitive, transitive] to make or cause something to make a
> short sharp sound
>
> (+ adv./prep.) The cameras clicked away.
>
> The bolt clicked into place.
>
> - adj. The door clicked shut.
>
> click something He clicked his fingers at the waiter.
>
> Polly clicked her tongue in annoyance.
>
> The corporal clicked his heels.
>
> The police officer clicked a pair of handcuffs around his wrists.

---

So, these are from dictionaries, "**the policeman snapped the handcuffs around her wrist**" and "**the police officer clicked a pair of handcuffs around his wrists**".

Can "**snap**" and "**click**" be used interchangeably or what are the **differences**?

Comment: If you want the idiomatic version of applying handcuffs = "snap on the cuffs". The officers snapped the cuffs on the felon.  Also, they "cuffed the felon".

Comment: Personally,  I would use click only in reference to the sound made by cuffs rather than the action of applying them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no significant difference. Both expressions mean that the handcuffs were quickly closed round the arrested person's wrist(s) with a sound described as either a snap or a click.